# Katalon Studio vs Selenium

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

I have been using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to test software for a long time. I recently installed tried [Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/katalon-studio/) and think it requires less knowledge of coding.

Will Katalon replace Selenium? Is it good to start tests in Katalon?

Comment: cant really say selenium can be replaced, but katalon technology is built on top of selenium which overcame multiple challenges faced when using selenium. A lot of manual testers can make their work simpler as katalon doesnt require a full coding knowledge. I have read that you can import a selenium project to katalon studio and execute it which is really a cool feature, instead of migrating scripts from selenium to katalon which is expensive interms of time.

Comment: Nominating this for reopen so it can be migrated to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think Katalon never replace Selenium cause it bases/inherits from Selenium.