# How do I decide which tool to shortlist for automation between Selenium and Katalon? Given the skillset is available for both

Tags: selenium, katalon-studio

How can I make a choice between Selenium and Katalon? I have resources for both, I mean the Selenium guys can learn Katalon fast enough.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not for software recommendations or opinions on things. It’s pretty hard to come up with facts about this, especially not knowing anything about your situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266507/katalon-studio-vs-selenium

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad scenario type question it all depends what type of application you want to work. what type of test strategy you want to follow on what technologies your resources are trained. what is the scope of testing you want to achieve.